# Get tab ID in order to update after creation

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

When a browser creates a new tab it starts off empty and then is updated with `about:blank` or `about:newtab`. I need JavaScript to be able to update this within the extension.

Currently I have;

```
browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleUpdate);
```

This allows me to know when a new tab is created and then when it is updated. After this I need to be able to update it again with something like this;

```
 var TabReplacement = {url: 'https://mycompany.com/newtab.html'};
    browser.tabs.update(TabReplacement);
```

I just need to be able to update the tab again in order to have a custom new tab but it shouldn't affect new tabs that are created by opening links in a new tab etc. I know that it needs to trigger when the event listener is activated.

Would you update the tab straight away or obtain the tab ID and then update via tab ID?

TLDR; I want the same function as:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...

  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "about:newtab": "https://www.google.com"
  },
  ...
}
```

Has in a Chrome manifest file but this isn't possible with edge.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, I guess you are asking for something like this where you want to use the Tab Id to update the tab.

```
function handleCreated(tab) {
var tabReplacement = {url: 'https://mycompany.com/newtab.html'}
    browser.tabs.update(tab.id,tabReplacement);
}

function handleUpdated(tab) {
var tabReplacement = {url: 'https://mycompany.com/newtab.html'};
    browser.tabs.update(tab.id,tabReplacement);
}
```

You can also get the tab index if you want to use it as shown below:
      browser.tabs.query({index:1})

Comment: For context please see here @Mohan, much easier way to explain [open this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MYMEDwxDw0wPmJEFXxCz-wJ1CpRLYt3_)